# Co-worker cc's his mother in work-related emails to the board of directors

Tags: email

During a recent disagreement between myself and my coworker, where some communication was handled via email between us and the board of directors, my co-worker cc'ed his mother in the business correspondence.

In my last email to all of them I asked why his mother was being cc'ed, and was she a consultant for our company; I know she is not, I was making a point.  He replied, "I'll cc my mom on any thing I like."

Of course, he could copy and forward the emails to anyone, as could any of us.  **I'm just wondering if this is heard of by anyone, and if it's worth pursuing further with management.**  Obviously, the BoD knows, since the emails were between all of us. I know it's unprofessional.  We don't have any of those confidential or business-only type clarifications in the email signatures (the way schools and larger companies do), we are a very small business.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49479/discussion-on-question-by-mseb-co-worker-ccs-his-mother-in-work-related-emails).

Answer (score 13):

Legal? No idea. Check with your HR team and a lawyer.

Appropriate? Absolutely not. Unless his mother is relevant to the business discussion, she has no reason to be copied in.

Pathetic? 100%

Answer (score 10):

Ask/Notify your manager if this behavior is acceptable and permitted in the company.

He should take the case further with his manager or HR if it's a problem, or the employee himself. You shouldn't have to fight this battle, only make your manager aware of the situation.

This is obviously not appropriate but if people are resisting your comments then notifying your authority is all you can do, and should do. Don't get into fights with your co-workers concerning regulations when you have people in your company which handle these things.

Note, however, that if this is strictly against the company's rules and you're pretty sure about it (they can sometimes be found on the company's internal website or in documents that are available to you) and if you have a department of security of some sort which handles issues like this it should be okay to report to them directly.

If in doubt, talk to your manager.